# could not run any code after flutter_upgrade

Tags: flutter

after i upgrade my flutter, i can't run any code. even the sample code throw exception and don't run.
i search some, but i can't resolve this problem.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-9d5b21729ff53dbf8eadd8bc97e0e30d77abec95.pom'.
               > Connect to mirror.vtwo.org:8850 [mirror.vtwo.org/5.152.221.178] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11m 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and this is my flutter doctor

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√]
> Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.18362.1016], locale en-US)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.3) [√] Android Studio (version 3.5) [√] VS Code (version
> 1.47.2) [√] Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!

thank's a lot for your answers

**UPDATE:
I update the Gradle and the problem is solving**

Comment: looks like a connection problem

Comment: Try Flutter Clean then rebuild also do that Invalidate Caches / Restart from Android Studio/Intellij

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj I clean and rebuild and restart android studio, but it throw same exception again.

Comment: Have you network issues on your machine? Do you navigate on network?

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj my network doesn't have any problem. today I update android SDK but still can not run any flutter app

Comment: @WehidBehrami, Remove your current flutter version → Delete from hard drive then download a new STABLE version, unzip it and re-create the same folder with a STABLE version. Maybe you have some beta that have issues :(

Comment: Note that.: Download it manually (1.20.0 is fine), from here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases then unzip it manually recreating a folder with the same name of the pre-existed version in same path

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj thanks for your answering. the problem is in Gradle. after i update the Gradle, the problem solved and the code run again.